# SQL subquery to return MIN of a column and corresponding values from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query

1. number of courses passed,
2. the earliest course passed
3. time taken to pass first course, for each student who is not currently expelled.

The tricky part here is 2). I constructed a sub-query by mapping the course table onto itself but restricting matches only to datepassed=min(datepassed). The query appears to work for a very sample, but when I try to apply it to my full data set (which would return ~1 million records) the query takes impossibly long to execute (left it for >2 hours and still wouldn't complete).

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Appreciate all your help!

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
  S.id,
  COUNT(C.course) as course_count,
  C2.course as first_course,
  DATEDIFF(MIN(C.datepassed),S.dateenrolled) as days_to_first
FROM student S
LEFT JOIN course C 
  ON C.studentid = S.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM course GROUP BY studentid HAVING datepassed IN (MIN(datepassed))) C2
  ON C2.studentid = C.studentid
WHERE YEAR(S.dateenrolled)=2013 
  AND U.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM expelled)
GROUP BY S.id
ORDER BY S.id
```

**Student table**

```
id  status  dateenrolled
1   graduated   1/1/2013
3   graduated   1/1/2013
```

**Expelled table**

```
id  dateexpelled
2   5/1/2013
```

**Course table**

```
studentid   course  datepassed
1   courseA 5/1/2014
1   courseB 1/1/2014
1   courseC 2/1/2014
1   courseD 3/1/2014
3   courseA 1/1/2014
3   couseB  2/1/2014
3   courseC 3/1/2014
3   courseD 4/1/2014
3   courseE 5/1/2014
```

Comment: Do you have indexes set up on your tables?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Yup indexes were set up. Not familiar with DDL/sqlfiddle but I'll check it out next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, course_count, days_to_first, C2.course first_course
FROM (
    SELECT S.id, COUNT(C.course) course_count, 
        DATEDIFF(MIN(datepassed),S.dateenrolled) as days_to_first,
        MIN(datepassed) min_datepassed
    FROM student S
        LEFT JOIN course C ON C.studentid = S.id 
    WHERE S.dateenrolled BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
        AND S.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM expelled)
    GROUP BY S.id
) t1 LEFT JOIN course C2 
    ON C2.studentid = t1.id
    AND C2.datepassed = t1.min_datepassed
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Took about 4 mins to return >1m records.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
SELECT s.id, f.course,
  COALESCE( DATEDIFF( c.first_pass,s.dateenrolled), 0 ) AS days_to_pass, 
  COALESCE( c.num_courses, 0 ) AS courses
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT studentid, MIN(datepassed) AS first_pass, COUNT(*) AS num_courses
  FROM course
  GROUP BY studentid ) c
ON s.id = c.studentid
JOIN course f
ON c.studentid = f.studentid AND c.first_pass = f.datepassed
LEFT JOIN expelled e
ON s.id = e.id
WHERE s.dateenrolled BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
AND e.id IS NULL
```

This query assumes a student can pass only one course on a given day, otherwise you can get more than one row for a student as its possible to have many first courses.

For performance it would help to have an index on dateenrolled in student table and a composite index on (studentid,datepassed) in courses table.

Comment: This worked well too! Took less than 1min though it dropped the students who graduated but had no passed courses (makes little sense in this context because I made up the variables). Thanks regardless! I'll vote it up too but I don't have enough reputation to do so.